# iOS: what's the best way to create a loop with multiple arguments/statements?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

Here's what I'm trying to do: I'm using the NSCalendar and NSDateComponents objects to create a loop that will display text and an image based on the date. So, in my viewdidload is this, pretty standard:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents =
[gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
```

Then I take the ints from month and day and have this:

```
if (month == 1 && day ==1)
[do this] //display text
[do this] //display image
```

here's where I need help: I originally created this as an if-else construct:

```
if (month == 1 && day == 1)
[do this]
[do this]
else if (month == 1 && day == 2)
[do this]
[do this]
```

but for some reason, as soon as I add the second statement I get an error (expected expression)

so I changed it to:

```
if (month == 1 && day == 1)
[do this]
[do this]
if (month == 1 && day == 2)
[do this]
[do this]
```

but now my second statement is being invoked even when if should return 0

is there a better way to do this using switch? Is it possible to have more than one expression as part of switch?

Comment: There is no loop here, only if statements.

Comment: Have forgotten to put the statements between the if and the else if into a block of code {}?

Answer (score 2):

You should use curly brackets:

```
if (month == 1 && day == 1) {
    [do this]
    [do this]
} else if (month == 1 && day == 2) {
    [do this]
    [do this]
}
```

Or

```
if (month == 1 && day == 1) {
    [do this]
    [do this]
}
if (month == 1 && day == 2) {
    [do this]
    [do this]
}
```

Comment: I think OP forgot to put them in his/her code and not only in this post because that matches the problems he/she mentioned: **"I get an error (expected expression)"** and **"my second statement is being invoked even when if should return 0"**

Comment: @sch: thanks. I had left out the curly braces. All the examples I had been working from so far had not shown them in an if statement.